# Nolock table hint for knex mssql

Tags: node.js, sql-server, knex.js

Is there any way of adding a sql table hint to a select statement using knex? Like *select* * *from* *table* **with (nolock)**, without writing the complete query in raw format?

Comment: Better idea: don't use `NOLOCK`. @AaronBertrand says [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: @Charlieface I do know not to overuse NOLOCK's. I just need to use it in some instances on knex where there is a large number of inserts into tables and selecting without nolocks could cause a lock on certain pages of the table while those inserts are happening. Which is very undesirable.